# Get H/D Serial number (Not Volumn Serial Number) for IDE and SATA

Tags: vb.net, serial-number

How can I read the hard disk serial number for IDE and SATA drives in VB.NET?
(I don't want the volume serial number).

This info should be gathered both for XP and Vista if possible without administrative rights.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582.aspx) (Windows Management Instrumentation) like this:

```
Dim mos As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia")

For Each mo As ManagementObject In mos.Get()
    Dim serial As String = mo("SerialNumber").ToString()
Next
```

Although, I've read about cases in which no serial number is returned using WMI. Another way to accomplish this would be through Platform Invocation Services (PInvoke).

[This](http://addressof.com/blog/posts/392.aspx) article includes a download in which the author implements [CreateFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx) and [DeviceIoControl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216(VS.85).aspx) to extract drive information through Interop services in VB .NET.

To use either of the above outlined methods you will need ADMIN rights, a utility which seems to circumvent this can be found [here](http://www.winsim.com/diskid32/diskid32.html). If your feeling adventurous the C++/Win32 [source code](http://www.winsim.com/diskid32/diskid32.cpp) is available for you to peruse. (Check out the function 'ReadPhysicalDriveInNTWithZeroRights()')

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function getHardDiskSerialNo()
    Dim serial As String

    Dim hd As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia")
    For Each dvs As ManagementObject In hd.Get()
        serial = dvs("SerialNumber").ToString()

    Next
    Return serial

End Function
```

Comment: This was flagged as low quality. Please expand on your code only answer to explain what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to get HDD Serial Number

```
    Dim HDD_Serial As String

    Dim hdd As New ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_DiskDrive")

    For Each hd In hdd.Get

        HDD_Serial = hd("SerialNumber")
        MsgBox(HDD_Serial)
    Next
```

Hope it Helps.