# Get serial number of all hard disks and partitions in it

Tags: windows, vbscript, vb6, wmi, hard-drive

I want to get all physical hard disk serial number(not volume serial number of drives) and partitions present in them.

Actually I used implementation from [DISKID32](https://www.winsim.com/diskid32/diskid32.html) to get all hard disks serial number , but this will not give partitions in the hard disk.So I planned to use some other method.

Below code gives get serial number of physical hard disk and also find partitions in the each harddisks.

```
ComputerName = "."
Set wmiServices  = GetObject ( _
    "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!//" _
    & ComputerName)
' Get physical disk drive
Set wmiDiskDrives =  wmiServices.ExecQuery ( _
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive")

For Each wmiDiskDrive In wmiDiskDrives
    MsgBox "Disk drive Caption: " _
        & wmiDiskDrive.Caption _
        & VbNewLine & "DeviceID: " _
        & " (" & wmiDiskDrive.DeviceID & ")"
    MsgBox  "Serial number" _
                & wmiDiskDrive.SerialNumber
    'Use the disk drive device id to
    ' find associated partition
    query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" _
        & wmiDiskDrive.DeviceID & "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"
    Set wmiDiskPartitions = wmiServices.ExecQuery(query)

    For Each wmiDiskPartition In wmiDiskPartitions
        'Use partition device id to find logical disk
        Set wmiLogicalDisks = wmiServices.ExecQuery _
            ("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" _
             & wmiDiskPartition.DeviceID & "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition")

        For Each wmiLogicalDisk In wmiLogicalDisks
            MsgBox  "Drive letter associated" _
                & " with disk drive = " _
                & wmiDiskDrive.Caption _
                & wmiDiskDrive.DeviceID _
                & VbNewLine & " Partition = " _
                & wmiDiskPartition.DeviceID _
                & VbNewLine & " is " _
                & wmiLogicalDisk.DeviceID

        Next
    Next
Next
```

It works perfectly in windows 8. But when I test in windows XP pc I got error while getting serial number i.e wmiDiskDrive.SerialNumber . All other objects are properly working.

Then I found that this property is not available in windows XP,windows server 2003 etc.
Now from above code I can get harddisk model number and the partitions in it,but I want serial number.

So how I can get hard disk serial number and their partitions( should work in all windows OS)? Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get H/D Serial number (Not Volumn Serial Number) for IDE and SATA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535902/get-h-d-serial-number-not-volumn-serial-number-for-ide-and-sata)

Comment: @jac It does not work in windows XP and also my question is not exactly duplicate of that question(as i asked it to work for win xp too). I want to get partitions based on harddisk serial number too. So please dont consider it as duplicate

Comment: you are probably going to need a 3rd party DLL to get that on pre-Vista/Non XP Pro machines...or some low level C++ code

Comment: Why do you even care about an operating system whose life-cycle ended more than half a year ago?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I too have been trying to solve this problem for a script I'm writing in Tcl some resource I've looked into for helping me have been the WMIC command and the DISKPART command. ![WMIC](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OZHh0.png) ![DiskPart](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CLPj7.png) Perhaps There's some potential there, but if you've already found a different solution, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem..

```
Public Function GetDriveSerialNumber(DrvL As String) As Long

         Dim fso As Object, Drv As Object
        Dim driveletter As String
        Dim DriveSerial As String
         Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        driveletter = DrvL


             Set Drv = fso.GetDrive(driveletter)


         With Drv
             If .IsReady Then
                 DriveSerial = Abs(.SerialNumber)
             Else
                 DriveSerial = -1
             End If
         End With


         Set Drv = Nothing
         Set fso = Nothing

         GetDriveSerialNumber = DriveSerial

     End Function
```

Comment: The serial number from your code is volume serial number and its not what i wanted. In my question I have mentioned that i dont want volume serial number. I want the unique hard disk serial number. Also i want to get all the partitions in the harddisk.